# How to configure ParsleyJs remote

Tags: validation, parsley.js

Here's my code:

```
    var myField = $('#fieldName').parsley({
        required : {
            required : true,
            errorMessage : 'Field is required'
        },
        custom : {
            custom : true,
            errorMessage : 'Fails custom validator'
        },
        remote : {
            url : '/register/check-duplicates',
            errorMessage : 'Already in use'
        }
```

This works as expected for the first two validators - 'required' and 'custom'.  When it gets to the 'remote' validator however, I get an error: `TypeError: url.indexOf is not a function`  Presumably I am configuring something incorrectly, but what?

I am planning to go with the default validator - i.e. response 2XX is a pass, response 4XX is a fail.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
 var myField = $('#fieldName').parsley({
    required : true,
    requiredErrorMessage : 'Field is required'
    custom : true,
    customErrorMessage : 'Fails custom validator'
    remote : '/register/check-duplicates',
    remoteErrorMessage : 'Already in use'
 })
```

Comment: Thanks Marc-Andre, this solved the initial problem however the remote error message is still not correct.  It says 'this value seems to be invalid', which is presumably a default error message?